# How to make a picture with different aspect ratio rounded using HTML/CSS that is supported on Android and iOS devices

Tags: android, html, ios, css, ionic-framework

I need to make a picture rounded using HTML and CSS. The solution should work on both iOS and Android devices.

I am aware that using `clip-path: circle` is one possible solution. But this solution is not supported on Android Devices (using Ionic and Cordova build for Project Target:Android 5.0.1, API level:21):

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjvRPd

Using `border-radius` works on both iOS and Android, however it requires the aspect ratio to be the same:

Example: http://codepen.io/soutlink/pen/zxdOzP

Comment: The first option you give works in the latest version of Chrome for Android. If you want to use a WebView, then I'd recommend you to use https://crosswalk-project.org/.

Comment: @se_bastiaan the solution that I am looking for needs to be compatible on the older versions of chrome on Android device.